# jQuery - Add a click handler after addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a class to an element when user clicks it:

```
$('.service-blurb').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('scrolls');
});
```

Now I want to add an event handler to the 'scrolls' class so when the user clicks again it scrolls.

```
$(document).on('click', '.scrolls', function() {
    //scrolls nicely to that service description
});
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
As soon as I click the first time on the '.service-blurb' element, it not only adds the class but it also scrolls. I want it to scroll only when the user clicks for the second time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that the event is bubbling out to the document, and then it checks whether you clicked on an element that matches `.scroll`, so it runs the delegated handler.

Change the first handler so it stops event bubbling.

```
$('.service-blurb').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('scrolls');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: could he also change his second click handler so that it's not attached to the 'document' but to element with the class '.scrolls' instead?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos No, because he's adding the `scrolls` class dynamically, so he has to use delegation. So the element won't have the class when he binds the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may not want to add the handler until the first click?

```
$('.service-blurb').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('scrolls');
    $(this).off('click'); // Disable this handler now that we're done

    $(document).on('click', '.scrolls', function() {
        //scrolls nicely to that service description
    });
});
```

Comment: It's still triggering the second click automatically :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you need event.preventDefault().

```
$('.service-blurb').click(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('scrolls');
    e.preventDefault;
});
```

For more... check here... https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/